# How do I remotely process (with low latency) Raspicam output?

Tags: linux, opencv, raspberry-pi, netcat

Due to limited processing power on the Raspberry Pi I am required to process the camera output on a remote machine. This machine is a Linux server and should use OpenCV to process the video data.

I found a solution which technically works but produces unacceptable high latency of around 10 seconds on 1280x720 resolution and around 17 seconds on a 640x360 resolution. Maybe this is caused by some buffer size being too big?

**So, my solution so far:**

On the Raspberry PI first use the raspivid command to capture the video, output this data to the standard output and transmit using netcat:

```
raspivid --timeout 0 --nopreview --intra 2 --width 1280 --height 720 --framerate 20 --output - | nc 192.168.1.108 5555
```

Then on the receiving part (actually called before transmitting):

```
nc -l -p 5555 | ./receiver
```

where receiver is a C++ application with the following source code:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    cv::VideoCapture cap("/dev/stdin");

    if(!cap.isOpened())
    {
        std::cout << "Could not open '/dev/stdin'!" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cv::namedWindow("Receiver");
    cv::Mat frame;

    while(cap.read(frame))
    {
        cv::imshow("Receiver", frame);
        cv::waitKey(30);
    }

    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

**Question**

How do I transmit my raspicam output to a (Linux) server and be able to process this data with an OpenCV enabled C++ application. Low latency (<400ms is acceptable) between transmission of a frame and actual processing of this frame is required.

edit: high resolution (1280x720 or higher) is also required.

Pardon my English if any mistakes made!

Comment: What is your problem? The latency?

Comment: Yes, latency is way too long.

Comment: Take a look to this post, maybe it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16750395/raspberry-pi-no-delay-10ms-video-stream

Comment: The resolution he's using is too low for my applications. A 360 degrees lens will be used. It should be possible at 720p 20FPS 200 ms latency. It works perfectly fine with mplayer!

Comment: I wonder if the pipe "|" is too small

Comment: My standard answer to buffering issues: `stdbuf -oL nc ...` Maybe that will work for you, too.

Comment: How can your latency increase by 70% when you transmit 1/4 of the data? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: The standard, on-board Ethernet is 100Mbps. If you plug in a Gigabit Ethernet adapter into a USB port, I found you can get double the bandwidth - i.e. 200Mbps. Yes, I understand bandwidth is different from latency but the two are related.

Answer (score 0):

You can use QWebSockets (Qt5). 
All you need is to convert the pictures from cv::Mat to QByteArray and stream them.
At 720p I get almost 15 FPS over LAN connection.